# ARM Docker Image support on AWS CodeBuild

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services

I've been trying to get a few different dockers images I've used for ARM cross-compiling setup in CodeBuild. In my project, if I choose one of the non-custom images it works, so I have narrowed it down the images I am supplying.

I have my own custom docker image (which works locally with the local code build script) hosted on ECR and I've also tried this image: https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/debian/

Both of these images, I get a provisioning failure: SINGLE_BUILD_CONTAINER_DEAD: Build container found dead before completing the build. Build container died because it was out of memory, or the Docker image is not supported

This is basically all of the information I am given.

Question: Should these images work? I am new to AWS in general and tearing my hair out trying to figure out why these will work when they work fine for me locally.